# How to get all rows from ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> having specific value in specific column?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Delete
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
         list.add(List.of("A","B","C","R"));
         list.add(List.of("E","F","G","F"));
         list.add(List.of("A","B","C","D"));
    }
}
```

I want to get all rows that have `"A"` in the first column. With the above example `list`, the results should be the 1st and 3rd rows only:

```
["A", "B", "C", "R"]
["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

I'd prefer a solution which uses Java 8 `stream`.

My other question, [How to find unique value of a column of a 2D ArrayList in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140579/how-to-find-unique-value-of-a-column-of-a-2d-arraylist-in-java?noredirect=1#comment93173854_53140579), may provide some additional context.

Comment: and what did you try further?

Comment: what do you mean by row? provide some input and output with minimal example

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                .filter(i -> list.get(i).get(0).equals("A"))
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: You state that you want all rows with '`"A"` in first columns'. Did you mean "column" or "columns" (i.e. are you looking for only just the first column, or more than one column)? You also state that the results should be the "1st and 2nd rows only", but those rows don't have `"A"` in the first column. The 1st and 3rd rows have `"A"` in the first column. The 2nd row doesn't even have `"A"`. You then state "the answer should be works for any columns and for any column's value". Does that mean you require people to write a function that accepts both a match column and a match value?

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify the issues I commented about above. Given that you had accepted an answer, the edits reflect that what you intended is reflected in that answer. Please review and revert the edit if you actually intended something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use the following :

```
List<List<String>> rows = list.stream()
                              .filter(l -> l.get(0).contains("A"))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here we check if the first index of the list contains "A" and then the resulting stream is collected to a list.

Output on printing the `List<List<String>> rows`

```
rows.forEach(System.out::println);
```

> [A, B, C, R]
>
> [A, B, C, D]

Comment: Please make sure you edit a question to add value to it and not remove the background related to. More or so, there was no detail in terms of what the OP has tried and you further removed the link from a previous attempt as well. Since you've entertained such a request, it [leads to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53170540/how-to-find-the-popular-item-from-a-column-in-2d-arraylist?noredirect=1&lq=1), that might just be a spoiler IMHO.

Comment: @nullpointer : I had removed it as that was an entirely different question and there wasn't any relation between the two apart from the fact that both questions had something to do with List<List<String>>. Also how does an attempt in another question even relevant to a new one?

Comment: @nullpointer you are so right.. when I answer such a question with no attempt, I get mercilessly down-voted.. feel sad that the community upvoted this question and this answer

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you don’t need a stream. The `List.removeIf` method is a bit overlooked and quite useful:

```
     list.removeIf(inner -> inner.size() <= 0 || ! inner.get(0).equals("A"));
```

For a different index, say, 3, you will need to replace both occurrences of `0` with `3`. You will probably want to wrap the whole thing in a method. Notice that this modifies the original list. Let’s dump the modified list to see the result:

```
     list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This prints:

> ```
> [A, B, C, R]
> [A, B, C, D]
> ```

If you wanted the result in a new list instead, you may either use a stream or simply copy the list using the `ArrayList(Collection)` constructor and then use the above on the copy.

Comment: @nullpointer The requirements you quote were self contradictory. I did my best to interpret. I may not have interpreted as intended. A farfetched justification might be that the result includes the 1st row, 1-based, and the 2nd row, 0-based. I don’t want to do *all* of the homework, so will leave to the asker to make this work for other indices and values, though I believe I have included a helpful hint or two on how.